# Calculate true/false for probability

Tags: c#, math

I have a rocket wich have 49% hit ratio. What is the formula to calculate hit (true/false) for that rocket?
I have many objects with different probabilities.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rand = new Random(); 

if(rand.Next(1, 101) <= rocketHitRatio)
//hit
else
//no hit
```

Answer (score 0):

Random.NextDouble() returns a number between 0.0 or greater and less than 1.0 . You just compare that result to your percent chance expressed as a double, if it is below or equal to the value of the hit chance you have a hit.

```
bool IsHit(Random rnd, double hitChance)
{
    return rnd.NextDouble() <= hitChance;
}

double rocketChance = 0.49;
bool hit = IsHit(_random, rocketChance);
```

Comment: I fixed my math. You just plug every number in to the formula 0.01 through 1.00

Comment: The formula is `percent hit chance <= the value you want to test normalized to the 0 to 1 range.`